# Debug the javascript part of Django project using Webstorm

Tags: javascript, django, debugging, webstorm

How can you get in the debug mode in webstorm to debug the frontend (implemented with javascript) in a Django project. I managed to import the js folder of my project but it's not possible to run and debug it through WebStorm, so for now I just run it through Eclipse and use the browser debugger so far. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible via JavaScript Debug run configuration: you need to specify the URL of your start page (like `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/index.html'`)
as 'URL to open' and set remote URL mappings accordingly (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver). Of course, you can't start Django server from WebStorm, but you can debug javascript served by it...